# Variance of Brownian Integral when the end point is specified

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the Brownian $W_u$. Suppose you are only considering realizations of this brownian that verify both $W_0=0$ and, for a specific (given) $t$, $W_t=a$.

Under these specific conditions, what is the conditional mean and variance of $I=\int_0^tW_udu$ ?

Edit : after a bit more search, I have learned that $W_u$ is then called a brownian bridge and managed to produce some results, although I am basically a beginner in stochastic calculus (don't have and never had any kind of course on the subject).

I have (I believe) no trouble proving that $I$ is gaussian.

For the mean, I obtain

$$E[I|W_t]=\int\limits_0^tE[W_u|W_t]du=\int\limits_0^t\frac{uW_t}{t}du=\frac{tW_t}{2}$$

For the variance, I obtain

$$var(I|W_t)=cov\left(\int\limits_0^tW_udu|W_t,\int\limits_0^tW_vdv|W_t\right)$$
$$=\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^tcov(W_udu|W_t,W_vdv|W_t)$$
$$=\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_0^t\left(min(u,v)-\frac{uv}{t}\right)dudv$$
$$=\frac{t^3}{12}$$

Is this correct ?

Comment: The variance part is definitely lacking some rigor. Note that in the identity, $\mathrm{var}(X\mid Y)=\mathrm{cov}(X\mid Y,X\mid Y)$, the LHS is well defined but the RHS has no meaning since $X\mid Y$ is not defined. Can you rephrase your computations?

Comment: I mean $X|Y$ as $X$ knowing $Y$ (standard notation). In this case, $var(I|W_t)$ is thus the variance of all realizations of $I$ that verify (or for which) $W_t$ has the specific considered value. I guess I could note this $var(I|W_t=a)$ if this is ambiguous. Then I'm just using $var(X)=cov(X,X)$ : I'm not sure I get your comment about $X|Y$ being "not defined" ?

Comment: Please reread carefully my comment: in the identity written in my comment, the LHS is **well defined** but the RHS has **no meaning** whatsoever. Again: $\mathrm{var}(X\mid Y)$ is well defined, this is a *random variable* and there are precise formulas defining it unambiguously. But which mathematical object would be $X\mid Y$? In other words: can you expand on this "standard notation" of yours?

Comment: I mean $X|Y$ as all occurences of $X$ that verify $Y$. Maybe you'd prefer it to be noted $var(X)|Y$, in any case, if you are ok with and understand  $var(X|Y)$, I'm not sure what more there is to get.

Comment: Additionally and in fact, your last comment is quite strange : $var(X|Y)$ is a simple function of $t$ and in no way a random variable. $X$ is a rv, $X|Y$ is a particular, well-defined subset of all $X$ realizations (and thus is a also rv), but $var(X|Y)$ plainly isn't.

Comment: Sorry but there are some serious definitional problems here: in full generality, for some random variables $X$ and $Y$, $E(X\mid Y)$ and $\mathrm{var}(X\mid Y)$ are random variables, $X\mid Y$ does not exist (and the string of words "subset of all $X$ realizations" cannot apply to cases, such as here, when $Y$ is continuous), and $\mathrm{cov}(X\mid Y,X\mid Y)$ is a horror. Note that, again in full generality, $$\mathrm{var}(X\mid Y)=E(X^2\mid Y)-E(X\mid Y)^2=E((X-E(X\mid Y))^2\mid Y).$$

Comment: As I have said before : in this case, $var(I|W_t)$ is intended as the variance of all realizations of $I$ that verify (or for which) $W_t$ has the specific considered value (you could name this specific value $a$ or whatever). I guess I could note this $var(I|(W_t=a))$ if the other notation is ambiguous. Once I've said that there is nothing left to understand, and what I'm trying to do is explained just the same in the first lines of the post.

Comment: If the notation for the calculus I made is not clear, and I can quite understand that it might be messy or unconventional (especially RHS), maybe just forget everything that was written in the OP after the first question, and see if you can answer it ? In the short term this is what I'm really interested in. Let's discuss proper notation of my original calculus afterwards (or proper calculus if I've made mistakes).